# how to display the date as a day/month/year format after adding 10 days to current date

Tags: javascript

so I got this function that adds 5 days to the current date, the only problem is that the date is displayed as "Mon May 30 2022 00:16:04 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)" I need a simple, clean format like 22/07/2002.

```
<div class="container-date">
  <p>Offer expires on <span id="date"></span></p>
</div>


ar d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 10);

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d ;
```

Comment: Not quite sure what `this.valueOf()` does but looks wrong.

Comment: well the code works fine.. I got it from stackoverflow

Comment: Did you test what `this.valueOf()` is inside your function `addDays()` before asserting that *the code works fine*? It looks off. `this` is an object, so what does `valueOf()` do for it?

Comment: Since you say you got the code somewhere (even here on SO), I'd suggest that you (1) learn what `new Date` does and expects, (2) use `console.log` or even browser dev tools to figure out logical errors. Without actually looking at errors/exceptions, it will be all the much harder to debug coding errors.

Comment: In this way, when you do present a problem, all (or most of the obvious) errors are not embedded in your question. Simply posting someone else's code lacks *context* if you yourself don't even know what it does for your particular goal.

Comment: hi, thanks for the advice. I edited the syntax, hopefully you can get a better idea on what I am trying to achive.  the code works fine, but I just want to display only the days, mont and year.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// Note this wont calculate 5days ahead ,it just gives the asked format!
var today = new Date();   
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2,'0');  
to the current date
var mm = String(today.getMonth()+1).padStart(2,'0');  
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();    
today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;    
console.log(today);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works good, but when I add 10 days insted of 03.06.2002 the output is 35.05,2022

Answer (score 1):

`date.toISOString().slice(0, 10):` Convert date to string and get first 10 character.
[toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) (`2022-05-29T23:03:31.782Z` to `2022-05-29`)

`date.split('-').reverse().join('/'):` Split string by `-`, `reverse`it for formatting and convert array to a string with `/` separator. (`2022-05-29` to `29/05/2022`)

```js
const addDays = (days) => {
  let date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  date = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  return date.split('-').reverse().join('/');
}
const date = addDays(5);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Format Date and add days to it

```
function formatDate(days = 10) {
  const dt = new Date();
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate() + days),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd/MM/yyyy"));
}

Execution log
5:11:55 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:11:54 PM  Info    03/06/2022
5:11:56 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 1):

## SUGGESTION

You can use [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) method to easily format `date` objects. See this quick sample below:

### SCRIPT

```
function test() {
  var d = new Date();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 5)), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
  console.log(formattedDate);
}
```

### Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work if the days overflow with the months.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add Days to Date</title>
</head>

<body>
    
<div class="container-date">
  <p>Offer expires on <span id="date"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
    
//Date class
var d = new Date();

//Returns the current day   
var day = d.getDate();
    
//Returns the current month
var month = d.getMonth();
    
//Returns the current year
var year = d.getFullYear();
    
    
//New Date Class for the current date plus added days
//Days overflowing will make a new month and a new year if needed
//see "https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp" for more info

var newDate = new Date(year, month, day+5);
    
//month indexes are 0-11 for Jan-Dec, so the added one is necessary
    
var dd = newDate.getDate();
var mm = newDate.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = newDate.getFullYear();

//for the double digit string
dd = dd.toString().padStart(2,"0");
mm = mm.toString().padStart(2,"0");

    
//Date string Message
var dateString = `${dd}/${mm}/${yyyy}`;

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = dateString;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```